# Assignment to variable gives segmentation fault in completely unrelated function

Tags: c, string, segmentation-fault, variable-assignment

I copied some code that simply reads a file to a string and prints the string from an older program. It was working fine, so I decided to modify it a bit. The new program is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    FILE *itemlist = fopen("itemlist", "r");
    char *currentstring, charbuffer[2];
    // char itemstart = 0;
    while (fgets(charbuffer, 2, itemlist)) {
        strcat(currentstring, charbuffer);
    }
    printf("%s", currentstring);
    return 0; 
}
```

And it works as expected. But when I uncomment the `itemstart` line, it gives a segmentation fault. I'm not even using it and as far as I'm concerned, initializing an char to 0 is not illegal. I thought it was an issue with types, then I changed it to a short and then to int and it was still giving a segfault.

But then I removed the `= 0` part and it worked again. Then I decided to put it back, debug the binary with gdb, and the segfault was at `strcat`.

How is this possible?

Comment: What is `currentstring` pointing at?

Comment: Nothing at the moment, it's just an empty string. When I make `currentstring` point to NULL, it segfaults.

Comment: That was rhetorical.  You are correct, it is pointing to *nothing*.  Random memory.  What do you think happens when you modify random memory?  Where did you think it was going to point, such that you could just randomly write to it?

Comment: Oh, that's right, I forgot. Every line in the text has different length and there's no length limit, that's why I didn't use malloc. I think I could read the line, get the length and then allocate, but this itemlist is going to read around 20000 items so I'm not sure if that's a good thing to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`currentstring` is a dangling pointer, so `strcat(currentstring, charbuffer);` results in undefined behavior.

Probably uncommenting `char itemstart = 0` initializes some memory to `0` and the access violation is made visible, however this is just a guess. Undefined behavior means anything can happen.

You should allocate memory for `currentstring`:

```
currentstring = malloc(10); //or whatever length you need
```

Comment: You corrected his code, but you didn't answer his question :)

Comment: This is going to be a program that reads an itemlist with the format `id = [name, properties, ...]` so the length of each line could be 10 or 150.

Comment: @EldritchConundrum I did. Undefined behavior. Read the answer again.

Comment: @user1002327 well then, you either allocate a large enough buffer or use a different approach.

Comment: The itemlist is something I can't remove, and a big enough buffer is probably going to waste a lot of memory. I need to read ~20000 items, do some processing, and writing everything back to another file (should be way smaller, around 200 items or so). But thanks for the answer, that seems to be the reason.

Answer (score 1):

You need to allocate some space for currentstring.

Answer (score 1):

Segfaults when uncommenting unrelated lines are made possible by the unsafeness of the C language. The end behavior of an incorrect program is determined by subtle choices made by the compiler.

When confronted to such madness, you should try to correct your code first. This is of course, not always easy. On a 8 lines program, you should be ok though.

Answer (score 1):

You must allocate space for `currentstring` variable and control the size of it for avoid segment fault/heap corruption.

```
#define MAX_BUFFER_SIZE 32
//...
FILE *itemlist = fopen("itemlist", "r");
char *currentstring = malloc(MAX_BUFFER_SIZE+1);
char *tmpbuf;
char charbuffer[2];
// char itemstart = 0;
int bytesloaded = 0;
while (fgets(charbuffer, 2, itemlist)) {

    if(bytesloaded + 2 > buf_size) {
       /* call realloc() */
        buf_size += MAX_BUFFER_SIZE;
        tmpbuf = realloc(currentstring, buf_size);
        if(tmpbuf == NULL) { /* Get off loop. Using break or return. */
             break; 
        } 
        currentstrig = tmpbuf;
     }
    memcpy(currentstring + bytesloaded, charbuffer, 2);
    bytesloaded += 2;
}
//... 
free(currentstring);
```

I haven't tested,but I believe that it works.